# Show array data in richtext box

Tags: c#, .net

I added a `RichTextBox` control to my form. I want to show the data in an `ArrayList` in the `RichTextBox`. How can I do this?

```
try
{
     string filepath = "";
     string filename = "";
     OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
     ofd.Filter = "XML files|*.xml";
     if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
          filepath = ofd.FileName;
          txtPath.Text = filepath + filename;
          XMLParser objxmlparser = new XMLParser();
          ArrayList al =objxmlparser.readDataLogXml(txtPath.Text);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  Also what's `readDataLogXml()`?

Comment: arraylist is declared in XMLParser class and it has some data as program executes. now I need to show arraylist data on richtextbox on form. readDatalogxml is method in xmlparser class.

Comment: An ArrayList is a collection of objects.  What kind of objects are in the ArrayList (string, int, short, etc..., or did your XMLParser create a custom object that you defined)?

Comment: If your collection happens to have some kind of objects that represent XML (i.e. hierarchical data) then you should give us an example of what data the array list will contain, and you need to specify how you want each data item formatted in your UI text box.

Comment: Unless you show what the data looks like nobody can effectively answer this.

Answer (score 0):

I think as long as objects in the ArrayList are simple data types, you could try

```
try
{
     string filepath = "";
     string filename = "";
     OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
     ofd.Filter = "XML files|*.xml";
     if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
          filepath = ofd.FileName;
          txtPath.Text = filepath + filename;
          XMLParser objxmlparser = new XMLParser();
          ArrayList al =objxmlparser.readDataLogXml(txtPath.Text);
          for (int i = 0; i < al.Count; i++)
          {
              yourRichTextBox.Text += string.Format("{0}\r\n", al[i].ToString());
          }
      }
 }
```

Otherwise, if the objects in the ArrayList are custom objects you created, then you need to override the ToString() method in the custom class that you defined

```
public class YourCustomClass
{
    // Your Custom Fields

    // Your Custom Methods

    public override string ToString()
    {
        // Format how you want this object to display information about itself
        // The {0}, {1}, etc... are place holders for your custom fields
        return string.Format("Put what you want to display here: {0} {1} {2}", customField1, customField2, customField3)
    }
}
```